# Flash to image script

Tags: php, flash, image-processing

Does anyone know of a script, preferably PHP-based that will allow conversion of a static flash to an image?

Comment: Static flash to image? If you wish to do this programatically, there's khtml2png (works on OS X and Linux); doing this for a Flash object in a webpage feels like an ugly hack though.

Comment: I am thinking of Flash because I think it is flexible enough to allow me build what I need: canvas a user can use to position 3D objects to build a picture and then convert to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're talking about converting a flash DisplayObject (which nearly everything in flash is) to a jpeg, as3 core libs has a fantastic jpeg exporter that I use on a regular basis. It sends the converted jpeg or png as raw post data, so you can pretty much do anything you want with it on the php side of things.

You can get the as3corelib package here: http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib - There's many many tutorials on getting the bitmap encoder up and running all over the web, and it's super simple, but if you need help with that I can help as well.

Comment: Great! I am far from writing the code at this point but this is a really good news. What I am trying to do is to have an interactive flash file where a user will be able to take flash objects, from a  library included, position them on a canvas and then create an image.

Comment: BTW, since I'm on this subject, I think I know the answer, but I'd ask anyway: is there a way to have 3D objects in flash  that can be rotated in any direction? Are there royalty-free already built objects available anywhere?

Comment: I haven't ever actually done it, but while flash 10 claims to be 3d capable, it's actually just rendering 2d objects in a fake 3d space using perspectives. For actual 3D (again, I haven't personally tested it), I've heard wonderful things about papervision 3D (http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/), and open source plugin for flash. As far as I understand you export a low poly model in COLLADA format, then import it to papervision, and animate it there. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: I hear flash destroys CPUs on complex models though, so I think you might be best at least editing models before importing them. There are 3D models out there that are royalty free, I think google's your friend here, as sometimes "free" doesn't really mean royalty free. I know turbosquid has some free models, but who knows what that means in terms of creative ownership. Here's a search for the free models on turbosquid: http://www.turbosquid.com/Search/Index.cfm?keyword=&media_typeid=2&max_price=0&show_mature=YES

Comment: Oh, and to get you started on the papervision stuff, lee brimelow has a nice basics tutorial on his site, you can watch it here: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=106